# what is the name of the slideshow script in wipro site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

what is the name of the image slide show at :

http://www.wipro.com/index.htm and where can I find the script for free plz? I need to use it in a page built with php, html,css, javascript.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/ ?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to know usage of elements of a website, look at the code source.

Image Flow : http://imageflow.finnrudolph.de/

Answer (score 0):

Uh...word of caution: Wipro is a horrifically bad IT outsourcing megacorp. I'd NEVER borrow any code that they use. Having had to work with them, I can tell you the code that comes from that operation is pretty much useless.

Comment: useless? what do u mean? borrowing? -  umm may be they used a free script.

Comment: I mean useless. Of no use. Wipro can't code. Stay away from anything they touch.